# How to draw with precision (e.g. a line) in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, paint, precision

I've been trying to make a drawing canvas in my app, but I'm unable to draw the points precisely. I'm using an OnTouchListener and I add every point in the historical pointer to the canvas and paint it with black.

Unfortunately, it's not working because it's not drawing all the points touched by the user (for example, when tracing a line). I'll show you an **example**:

[image]

The code I'm using is the following:

```
 public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }
    public DrawView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle) {
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Point point : points) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 12, paint);
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Point point = new Point();

        final int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
        final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
        for (int h = 0; h < historySize; h++) {
            for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
                point.x=event.getHistoricalX(p, h);
                point.y=event.getHistoricalY(p, h);
                points.add(point);
                invalidate();
                Log.d("debug","pointer: "+
                    event.getPointerId(p)+" "+ event.getHistoricalX(p, h)+" "+ event.getHistoricalY(p, h));
            }
        }

        /*point.x = (int)event.getX();
        point.y = (int)event.getY();*/
        Log.d("debug", "really saved: "+
                event.getX()+" "+ event.getY());
        //points.add(point);
        //invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
class Point {
    float x, y;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: whats wrong with your sample image?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are only drawing points you get touch events for. If the user moves quickly you only get some of the points.  The solution is to draw lines between consecutive points rather than just the points themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing many points here, you should capture all points here rather than capturing historical points only.

Check this - 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458042/Touch-handling-in-Android